# Spock test cases doesn't make a relationship of domain classes in Grails?

Tags: grails, spock

I have a Spock test case, in which the `setup` block looks like this :

```
setup: "set the required objects"
        def company = new Company(shortName:"infyyy",fullName:"infoysys",
            region:"tamilnadu" ,email:"a@ac.com" ,telphone:34343433,fax:34343433).save(failOnError:true)
        def project = new Project(name:"testing")
        def userInstance = new User(username:username,password:password,
            company:company,project:project,pt:["dummy"]).save(failOnError:true)
        def tasksInstance = new Tasks(title:"testingwork",startDate:(new Date()-4),endDate:(new Date().clearTime()-6),description:"blah blah",project:project,completed:true,user:userInstance).save(failOnError:true)
```

And more over, the `Tasks` domain class looks like this :

```
class Tasks {
    static belongsTo = [ user : User, project: Project ]
        //other code
}
```

And `User` class is like this :

```
class User  {
        static hasMany = [ holidays : Holiday, tasks : Tasks, pt:String, project: Project ]
        //other code
}
```

But when I run my test and my test fails(not with an error message, but it fails in the `then` block of my Spock test) and I find a error in it. My setup doesn't create any relationship between `User` and `Tasks`, which makes my test to fail.

The controller code, which I'm trying to test is :

```
def todaysTasks() {
        def user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
        def choice = params.managersProject
        params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10,100)
        def search = Tasks.createCriteria().list(max: params.max as Integer, offset: params.offset as Integer, order: params.order as String, sort : params.sort) {
            and {
                  project {
                      like('name',"${choice}")
                  }
                  eq('endDate', new Date().clearTime())
            }
        }
        println "todays task selected project is " + search
        [tasksInstanceList : search, tasksInstanceTotal: search.getTotalCount() ]
    }
```

The `println` in the above test prints `0`. Why does this happen even though I'm making the `endDate` in my test less than today's date?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Please post a test that fails and an error message with stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, GORM does not auto-populate relationships, by following a belongsTo relationship.

I always do the following.

```
def u=new User(...)
u.addToTasks(
   title:"testingwork",
   startDate:(new Date()-4),
   endDate:...
)
u.save()
```

Note that I have not created a task object. I have passed the Map of values directly to addToX... this emphasizes that the added object belongs to User and should be instantiated and saved by GORM.

Comment: Well, you will need to post more code so people can start to put the problem in context, because this should work

Comment: do you mock your domain classes with @MockFor or mockDomain?.... That is what i mean by context,  we don't need the controller code if you have already localized the issue being in your setup code inside your test.

Comment: Well this is an integration test. Why do I need to mock it?

Comment: In that case, I'm out of ideas, checking out. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (and you shouldn't) test criteria queries in your unit tests. Criteria queires are not supported in grails (and spock) unit tests. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231154/how-to-test-a-grails-service-that-utilizes-a-criteria-query-with-spock) question for possible solutions.